# How to retrieve a particular Facebook post using post_id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

In my application, there is a case where I want to retrieve the content (message) of a particular Facebook post. I am able to get the postid id for that particular post, but I am not able to get the content associated with that id. I could not find any [FQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Query_Language) query to get the post message with post_id or a [Graph API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook_Platform#Graph_API) [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator).

I have this URL to get the all posts, `../100005002784039/posts?fields=id,name,message`,  but I want only a particular message of the post while passing the post id.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make the following query to the API-

```
/POST_ID
```

Comment: how to pass the acces token to this url? can u please give the complete url how it gonna look

Comment: if you are using PHP SDK- `$facebook->api('/POST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN')`. If JS SDK - `FB.api('/POST_ID?access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN')`

Comment: is ythis correct "https://graph.facebook.com/"+fbTrace.getFbPostId()+"?access_token="+TOKEN+""??  or just access_token=TOKEN is enough

Comment: What do you mean by "TOKEN"? btw, the link you mentioned is correct , use that

Comment: I don't know what and how are you getting the exception in this very simple query. I tested here with no exception.

Comment: yeahh iam getting right now..can u look at my answer , am i doing right how to read the data from the url? do i need to use the json? if sow can u plzz give some idea?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23478/discussion-between-sahil-and-teekib)

Comment: yeahh sure..i am in chat can u come to chat

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to sahil, my [URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator) is like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/"+PostId()+"?access_token=Token);
```

#### Code

```
URL fbmsg = new URL("https://graph.facebook.com/"+trace.getFbPostId()+"?access_token="+TOKEN+"");
URLConnection yc = fbmsg.openConnection();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));

String inputLine;

String s = "";

while ( (inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(inputLine);

Log.d(TAG, "getPostId trace getFbPostId " + inputLine);
s = s + inputLine + "n";
Log.d(TAG, "getPostId trace getFbPostId " + s);
in.close();
System.out.println(s);
```